# Documentation on Cycles BVH traversal and intersection algorithm

Tags: cycles-render-engine, documentation, bvh

Newbie to blender/cycles here.
Wondering if there are any documents/papers which explain the algorithm used in Cycles for BVH traversal and intersection?
Making sense of the code will be much easier if I can read about the algorithm/math first. 
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks much,
Gaurav.

Comment: Perhaps this can be of help: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Render/Cycles/BVH  especially the paper linked at the bottom and in general more information about Cycles https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Render/Cycles

Comment: thank you. this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The [wiki page for Cycles' BVH](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Render/Cycles/BVH) links to three publications that it implements. Below you can find the links to the papers* as well as the abstracts.

(*) The links are different from the ones in the wiki, because one of them returns a 404 and another one is very slow.

[Stich, Martin, Heiko Friedrich, and Andreas Dietrich. "Spatial splits
   in bounding volume hierarchies." *Proceedings of the Conference on
   High Performance Graphics 2009*. ACM, 2009.](https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/77714/sbvh.pdf)

> Bounding volume hierarchies (BVH) have become a widely used
>   alternative to kD-trees as the acceleration structure of choice in
>   modern ray tracing systems. However, BVHs adapt poorly to nonuniformly
>   tessellated scenes, which leads to increased ray shooting costs. This
>   paper presents a novel and practical BVH construction algorithm, which
>   addresses the issue by utilizing spatial splitting similar to
>   kD-trees. In contrast to previous preprocessing approaches, our method
>   uses the surface area heuristic to control primitive splitting during
>   tree construction. We show that our algorithm produces significantly
>   more efficient hierarchies than other techniques. In addition, user
>   parameters that directly influence splitting are eliminated, making
>   the algorithm easily controllable.

---

[Wald, Ingo, Solomon Boulos, and Peter Shirley. "Ray tracing deformable scenes using dynamic bounding volume hierarchies." *ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG) 26.1 (2007)*: 6.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.220.9438&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> The most significant deficiency of most of today’s interactive ray
>   tracers is that they are restricted to static walkthroughs. This
>   restriction is due to the static nature of the acceleration structures
>   used. While the best reported frame-rates for static geometric models
>   have been achieved using carefully constructed kd-trees, this paper
>   shows that bounding volume hierarchies (BVHs) can be used to
>   efficiently ray trace large static models. More importantly, the BVH
>   can be used to ray trace deformable models (sets of triangles whose
>   positions change over time) with little loss of performance. A variety
>   of efficiency techniques are used to achieve this performance, but
>   three algorithmic changes to the typical BVH algorithm are mainly
>   responsible. First, the BVH is built using a variant of the “surface
>   area heuristic” conventionally used to build kd-trees. Second, the
>   topology of the BVH is not changed over time so that only the bounding
>   volumes need be re-fit from frame to frame. Third, and most
>   importantly, packets of rays are traced together through the BVH using
>   a novel integrated packet-frustum traversal scheme. This traversal
>   scheme elegantly combines the advantages of both packet traversal and
>   frustum traversal, and allows for rapid hierarchy descent for packets
>   that hit bounding volumes, as well as rapid exits for packets that
>   miss. A BVH-based ray tracing system using these techniques is shown
>   to achieve performance for deformable models comparable to that
>   previously available only for static models.

---

[Dammertz, Holger, Johannes Hanika, and Alexander Keller. "Shallow bounding volume hierarchies for fast SIMD ray tracing of incoherent rays." *Computer Graphics Forum. Vol. 27. No. 4. Oxford, UK*: Blackwell Publishing Ltd, 2008.](http://cg.ivd.kit.edu/publications/pubhanika/2008_qbvh.pdf)

> Photorealistic image synthesis is a computationally demanding task
>   that relies on ray tracing for the evaluation of integrals. Rendering
>   time is dominated by tracing long paths that are very incoherent by
>   construction. We therefore investigate the use of SIMD instructions to
>   accelerate incoherent rays. SIMD is used in the hierarchy
>   construction, the tree traversal and the leaf intersection. This is
>   achieved by increasing the arity of acceleration structures, which
>   also reduces memory requirements. We show that the resulting
>   hierarchies can be built quickly and are smaller than acceleration
>   structures known so far while at the same time outperforming them for
>   incoherent rays. Our new acceleration structure speeds up ray tracing
>   by a factor of 1.6 to 2.0 compared to a highly optimized bounding
>   interval hierarchy implementation, and 1.3 to 1.6 compared to an
>   efficient kd-tree. At the same time, the memory requirements are
>   reduced by 10–50%. Additionally we show how a caching mechanism in
>   conjunction with this memory efficient hierarchy can be used to speed
>   up shadow rays in a global illumination algorithm without increasing
>   the memory footprint. This optimization decreased the number of
>   traversal steps up to 50%.